# Why DartPad gives a different result from Android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, oop, dart

While I was learning Dart and Flutter, I was trying to implement a simple class with 3 instance variables and a constructor with named parameters that uses the constructor syntactic sugar, here it is the code for that class:

```
class Story {
  String storyTitle;
  String choice1;
  String choice2;

  Story({this.storyTitle, this.choice1, this.choice2});
}
```

This works fine in Android Studio and the app uses the instance variables just fine. When I tried this in DartPad, I got the following errors:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
  Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:dartpad_sample/main.dart'.
  lib/main.dart:6:15:
Error: The parameter 'storyTitle' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 
 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 Story({this.storyTitle, this.choice1, this.choice2});
          ^^^^^^^^^^
 lib/main.dart:6:32:
Error: The parameter 'choice1' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 
 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 Story({this.storyTitle, this.choice1, this.choice2});
                           ^^^^^^^
 lib/main.dart:6:46:
Error: The parameter 'choice2' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 
 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
 Story({this.storyTitle, this.choice1, this.choice2});
                                         ^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

***According to my understanding of the documentation this code should work just fine as it does on Android Studio, any idea why it's throwing that error here and not there ? Is this code valid ?***

Comment: in dartpad you have "null safety" feature turned on - see the "Null Safety" switch on the bottom of the page

Comment: dartpad is using null safety by default, while you probably don't have the latest flutter version in your machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an older version of dart on android studio. In dart pad you have the newest version which have null safety enabled. If you want the dartpad code to work you can add required in the constructor for each parameter to let dart know you have to supply it.

like that:

```
class Story {
  String storyTitle;
  String choice1;
  String choice2;

  Story({required this.storyTitle, required this.choice1, required this.choice2});
}
```

If you want to have the same version on android studio you can change the pubspec.yml environment part to start from 2.12.0 which enables null safety

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```